# Error on my PDO Construct - Php

Tags: php, pdo

It's whining of line 6: `Warning: PDO::__construct() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given`

Along with a line 7 error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
```

How do I fix this? I've tested the query and it works fine..

```
<?php

## Loop through results from mysql
try{
    #connection string
        $dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=thedb',array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
        $q = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT thecol FROM thetbl");
    #call stored proc
        $q->execute();
    #get the rows into an array
        $result = $q->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $r){
            $xmlUrl = $r['FW_ArtSrcLink'];
            $ConvertToXml = simplexml_load_file($xmlUrl);
            # -> Setup XML
            $newsStory = $ConvertToXml->channel->item;
        }   

    # -----> Load News Stories
        for($i = 0;$i<sizeof($newsStory); $i++){

    # Source of Article Info-->
            $SrcTitle=$newsStory[$i]->title;
            $SrcLink=$newsStory[$i]->link;

    # Actual News Article Info -->
            $title=$newsStory[$i]->title;
            $desc=$newsStory[$i]->description;

    # Output Results ------------>      
            echo '<hr>';
            echo '<strong>'.'Title:'.$title.'</strong>'.'(via: <a href=\''.$SrcLink.'\'>'.$SrcTitle.'</a>'.'<br />';
            //echo 'Link:'.$link.'<br />';
            echo 'Description'.$desc.'<br>';
            echo '<hr>';
        }
} // try

catch(Exception $e){

    $errorStored = $e->getMessage() . ' on ' .'/errors/fanwire_loop.php';  #where errors are stored
    $pageDateOfError = '/aggregate_looping.php'.date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); #inc the file and date into the file too
    file_put_contents($errorStored,$pageDateOfError, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
} // catch

#Load in File


/*************************************************



$xmlUrl ="http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/rss/mlb/news";
$ConvertToXml = simplexml_load_file($xmlUrl);



# -> Setup XML
$newsStory = $ConvertToXml->channel->item;

# -----> Load News Stories
for($i = 0;$i<sizeof($newsStory); $i++){

    // Source of Article Info-->
    $SrcTitle=$newsStory[$i]->title;
    $SrcLink=$newsStory[$i]->link;

    // Actual News Article Info -->
    $title=$newsStory[$i]->title;
    $desc=$newsStory[$i]->description;


    echo '<hr>';
    echo '<strong>'.'Title:'.$title.'</strong>'.'(via: <a href=\''.$SrcLink.'\'>'.$SrcTitle.'</a>'.'<br />';
    //echo 'Link:'.$link.'<br />';
    echo 'Description'.$desc.'<br>';
    echo '<hr>';
}

***********************************************/

?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're initializing the PDO object incorrectly, the second parameter of the constructor should be the username, not an array of options.

```
$dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=thedb',array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
```

should be,

```
$dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=thedb',
                  'yourusername',
                  'yourpassword',
                  array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
```

See the [PHP manual page for PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) for more information.

The second error you're getting because the `$dbconn` object wasn't created properly due to the first error.

Comment: There is a comma missing after the password.

Answer (score -2):

Can u try

```
$dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=thedb');
$q = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT thecol FROM thetbl", array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
```

Comment: To enable code highlighting and the monospace font (which is easier to read) please indent each code line with four spaces. Also texting abbreviations and short answers aren't the philosophy here at SO. You should strive to write quality responses and in return you will receive positive rep points.